# MonoidK and Monad relation

Tags: scala, scala-cats, category-theory

I'm trying to understand well known phrase `A monad is just a monoid in the category of endofunctors` and map some category theory concepts to `cats` library.

There is a `MonoidK` typeclass in `cats` and it's polymorphic on `combineK` method. So one instance of this typeclass looks like monoid in the category of endofuctors if we parametrize it with functor.

What is the difference between `MonoidK` and `Monad` in terms of category theory if we assume that we can parametrize `MonoidK` only by functors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two notions of monoid: [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) in algebra and [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_(category_theory)) in category theory. Latter are more abstract version of former. Former can be considered as very specific partial case of latter. Let's call them monoid (1) and monoid (2).

`MonoidK` is monoid (1) for higher-kinded `F[_]`. You know how to "multiply" two elements of type `F[A]` and the "unit" of type `F[A]`.

`Monad` is monoid (2) for functors. You know how to "flatten" `F[F[A]]` into `F[A]` and how to "pack" `A` into `F[A]`.